# Python Creating dictionary from list

Tags: python, dictionary

EDIT:

I want to create a dictionary where the first number is the key and the number next to it is the number of values for that key. So the first row has a 1 and a 2 which means key 1 has 2 values and those values are in the next row. The third row has a 2 and 3 which means key 2 has 3 values and those values are 4,3,1.

The fifth row has a 3 and a 4 which means key 3 has 4 values and the 4 values are 5,4,2,1.

I want to know how to make a dictionary that can create a dictionary like this:

{1: [2,3], 2: [4,3,1], 3:[5,4,2,1]...}

```
1 2
2 3
2 3
4 3 1
3 4
5 4 2 1
4 4
8 3 5 2
5 7
15 11 8 9 6 3 4
6 2
9 5
7 3
14 13 8
8 5
12 11 5 4 7
9 6
26 22 15 10 6 5
10 3
20 17 9
11 4
16 12 5 8
12 5
16 14 13 11 8
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) so far?

Comment: Where are the lines of numbers coming from?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make dictionary from list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19439472/make-dictionary-from-list)

Comment: Looks like one of your classmates is working on this problem as well.  See the link in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you can describe your problem better, you can translate it into Python directly.

You want to take pairs of lines, split each line into separate numbers, and map the first number in the first line to the list of numbers in the second line.

So, let's start by pairing up the lines. (This is the only tricky bit—but there are about 3000 questions on SO that show you the two easy ways to do it.)

```
pairs = zip(*[iter(lines)]*2)
```

Now, for each pair:

```
for first, second in pairs:
```

… split each line into separate numbers:

```
    first_numbers = map(int, first.split())
    second_numbers = map(int, second.split())
```

… and map the first number in the first line to the list of numbers in the second:

```
    d[first_numbers[0]] = second_numbers
```

---

```
>>> lines = '''1 2
... 2 3
... 2 3
... 4 3 1'''.splitlines()
>>> d = {}
>>> pairs = zip(*[iter(lines)]*2)
>>> for first, second in pairs:
...     first_numbers = map(int, first.split())
...     second_numbers = map(int, second.split())
...     d[first_numbers[0]] = second_numbers
>>> d
{1: [2, 3], 2: [4, 3, 1]}
```

If you want to use the second number in the first line to verify the length, you can just add this:

```
...         if first_numbers[1] != len(second_numbers):
...             raise ValueError('Expected {}, got {}'.format(
...                 first_numbers[1], len(second_numbers)))
```