# Make dictionary from list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

So I created a list like this:

```
list = [line.strip() for line in open('file.txt','r')]
```

This is a snippet of my list.

```
[
 '1 2',
 '2 3',
 '2 3',
 '4 3 1',
 '3 4',
 '5 4 2 1',
 '4 4',
 '8 3 5 2',
 '5 7',
 '15 11 8 9 6 3 4',
]
```

I want to create a dictionary where the first number is the key and the number coming after are values but I want it in int form.

I don't know how to use the classes involved with dictionary.

Comment: *Show* exactly what you want - don't make people try to guess.  For example, do you want dict with ints as keys and lists of ints as values?  If so, for your example input do you want 2 to map to [3] or to [3, 3] (2 appears twice as the first number).  What do you want 5 to map to?  [4, 2, 1], [7], [4, 2, 1, 7], or something else?  Etc.

Comment: This won't work for your list, because there would be two keys for '2', '4' and '5', and `dict` keys must be unique.  You will lose data.

Comment: There are no "classes involved with dictionary" except `dict` itself.

Answer (score 5):

This should do the trick:

```
In [3]: arrs = [map(int, line.strip().split()) for line in open('file.txt')] 
In [4]: first2rest = dict( (arr[0], arr[1:]) for arr in arrs)

In [5]: first2rest
Out[5]: {1: [2], 2: [3], 3: [4], 4: [4], 5: [7], 8: [3, 5, 2], 15: [11, 8, 9, 6, 3, 4]}
```

Let's take it apart. This part splits up each line in your file on spaces and converts them to ints:

```
map(int, line.strip().split())
```

Then this part creates the dictionary of the first item in the row to the rest:

```
first2rest = dict( (arr[0], arr[1:]) for arr in arrs)
```

However, as @SethMMorton pointed out, you will lose data as the file you listed includes the same key multiple times.